# Angular 7 - How to Route to A New Window Location or File

Tags: angular, routes

In my app.module.ts I have a bunch of paths, but the two I want to focus on are these:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'www.site.fake', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', component: LoginComponent }
```

All I want to do is be able catch blank paths and send them to a different site.  So if you enter as www.mysite.com you get redirected. Vs. www.mysite.com/wrongpath = login component or www.mysite.com/matchedPath = to correct component.

Or do you have to create a `BlankComponent` and set the location in there?

Will the ** catch the redirected site link as a unknown route?

Comment: What are you asking with this code?

Comment: Definitely need more detail here. What do you *want* this to do? What is it currently doing?

Comment: @srknzl - add info in of what exactly I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @TheBatman see above.

Answer (score 0):

we can call `**` as wild card route and it will catch all the paths that the app doesn’t know. Make sure the wild card route is the last route of your routes because routes are read from top to bottom. If you mention wild card route in the beginning or in middle of your routes list all the bellow routes also get as unknown routes. 
eg:

```
{path: ‘not-found’ , component: ‘NotFoundComponent’}
{path: ‘**’ , redirectTo: ‘/not-found’}
```